# Garbled SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox() output?

Tags: c, character-encoding, sdl-2

Using `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox()` we should show a helping window but on my screen, it do not show the right characters, as if the encoding was wrong:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Below is the concerned code:

```c
void show_help_message_box()
{
  const char* message =
      "Press 'h' to open the help message box (here).\n"
      "Press 'r' to restart.\n"
      "Press 'z' to undo.\n"
      "Press 'y' to redo.\n"
      "Press 's' to save your current game.\n"
      "Press 'l' to load a game.\n"
      "Press 'q' or 'escap' to quit.\n";

  SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_INFORMATION, "Help", message, NULL);
}
```

I'm on Manjaro Linux 22.0.4

Comment: This problem seems to be [specific](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/4800) to [Manjaro](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sdl2-message-boxes-still-display-using-unintelligible-tamil-font-because-it-is-the-default-iso8859-font/132609). I suggest reporting this issue to manjaro and/or popping it on SDL bugtracker.